# Angular socket: 1 emit - 1 subcribe на него - 2 реакции

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs

Доброе утро, буду очень благодарна если кто то сможет мне помочь. Ситуация следующая: у нас есть socket.on. Внутрь передается функция которая емитит данные. В моем случае они равны undefined. В компоненте происходит подписка на этот емит, я получаю данные и вывожу их. В какой то момент по неизвестной мне причине у меня происходит 1 емит, но 2 реакции на него в подписке. Как такое может быть? И как ограничится только одной реакцией? (Tape никакого эффекта не дает)

```
        socketService {

          public connectToRequestHub(): void {
            this.dataChangeHubProxy.on('newRequestArrived', () =>{
            this.onATRequestChanges.emit();
           });
          }

          public startWsConnection(): void {
             this.connection = $.hubConnection();
             this.dataChangeHubProxy = 
               this.connection.createHubProxy('DataChangeHub');
             this.connection.url =
               this.appService.baseUrl.value + environment.signalrURL;
             this.connection
               .start()
               .done(() => {
                  this.registerSession();
                  this.registerChangeRequest();
                  this.connectionStarted$.next(true);
             })
           }

           public closeConnections(): void {
             if (this.connection) {
             this.connection.stop();
             this.dataChangeHubProxy.off('matrixDataChanged');
             this.connectionStarted$.next(false);
           }
        }
      }
    
  MyComponent {

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.socketSubscription = this.signalrService.connectionStarted$
          .pipe(first((val) => !!val))
          .subscribe(() => {
            this.ATRequestReceived();
          });
         }
     public ATRequestReceived(): void {
       this.signalrService.onATRequestChanges.subscribe(() => {
         this.newRequestReceived();
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код, потому что не понятно в чем может быть ошибка. Возможно у вас дублируется подписка на событие. Может еще что-то. Сейчас любой ответ похож на тыканье пальцем в небо)

Comment: Добавила немного кода

Comment: Вы создаёте по подписке каждый раз когда меняется статус соединения

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо, вы были правы. Mоя подписка создавалась дважды